# jQuery UI accordion and box-sizing: border-box

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm just playing around with jQueryUI for the first time and am very excited for what I can do with it. However, I seem to have run into problems quite quickly since I am using box-sizing: border-box on my pages.

For instance, if I have this basic HTML on the page (the text inside the accordion tabs is more plentiful in my real page, this is just for demo purposes):

```
<div id='accordion'>
<h3>Header 1</h3>
<div>This is <a href="#">paragraph one</a>.</div>
<h3>Header 2</h3>
<div>This is <a href="#">paragraph two</a>.</div>            
<h3>Header 3</h3>
<div>This is paragraph three.</div>
</div>
```

I can turn it into an accordion with jQuery: `$('#accordion').accordion()`.

However, if box-sizing is set to border-box with:

```
* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

Then there is a very unpleasant "snap" to the accordion sections whenever I open one up (at the very end). If I remove the box-sizing setting (not a possible, permanent solution) then the "snap" goes away.

Can it really be the case that I can't use jQueryUI accordions simply because I've set box-sizing to border-box? I suppose I could modify their code to work with box-sizing... but obviously I'd prefer to avoid that (in part because I'm not competent enough to do that properly).

I was surprised to see that this hadn't been asked before... so I'm guessing it's a painfully obvious solution that I'm just unaware of.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see my responses to dfsq below. The problems seem to be related to the 'auto' option in heightStyle: (1) box-sizing: border-box doesn't work with 'auto'; (2) setting a parent div's width doesn't work with 'auto' either!

Comment: Bug was created on jqueryui.com: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [heightStyle](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyle) option:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: 'content'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HNp5r/

I'm not sure why it fixes the problem though.

Comment: Hmmm, that's very interesting. Will investigate further... Also, jsfiddle.net is a GREAT service, thanks for linking to it.

Comment: FWIW, I was fiddling around with heightStyle and noticed that 'auto' wasn't doing on my page what it was doing on jsfiddle. I discovered that if the width of the containing panel is set then 'auto' simply breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/HNp5r/3/. So it appears that this accordion widget has some wonky height-calculating-code beyond just the box-sizing stuff :(

Comment: Tentative conclusion: the 'auto' option for heightStyle breaks if: (a) width is set on parent panel, and (b) box-sizing: border-box is set. However, the 'content' option works under both of these circumstances. I would guess this is simply a bug. Very disappointing, but thanks for your help!